# Unable to insert data in MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my code

```
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password');
mysql_select_db('db');
mysql_query("INSERT INTO metabase(url, title, image, description) VALUES('http://www.imgur.com/', '$title', '$image', '$descr')") or die();
```

It does not show any error but the values are not inserted in database. My table name is metabase. url, title, images are varchar(255) and description text. This is the error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's visual storytelling community. Explore, share, and discuss the best visual sto' at line 1
```

This is the description

```
The Internet's visual storytelling community. Explore, share, and discuss the best visual stories the Internet has to offer.
```

So it is because of `'` how do i correct it?

Comment: What are the types of the fields in the database and do you have error reporting on?

Comment: Change `die()` to `die(mysql_error())`

Comment: or die(mysql_error()); does not show any errors?

Comment: Check the return value of mysql_connect and mysql_select_db - they may have failed.

Comment: @TiiJ7 It says one error in SQL syntax.

Comment: Add the exact error to your Question (edit it).

Comment: Please, [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://us1.php.net/pdo).

Comment: Do not use deprecated `mysql_*` API. Use `mysqli_*` or PDO with prepared statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [MYSQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.overview.php) because `MySQL_` is depreciated. Not only that, you're not escaping your values and are exposing yourself to some issues such as MySQL injection

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db","root","password");
$query = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `metabase` (url, title, image, description) VALUES(:url, :title, :image, :descr)");
$query->bindValue(":url", "http://www.imgur.com", PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindValue(":title", $title, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindValue(":image", $image, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindValue(":descr", $descr, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
```

Comment: Hey Jake I got `unexpected ':' error` on line 37 which is `$pdo->bindValue(:url,"http://www.imgur.com/", PDO::PARAM_STR);`

Comment: Sorry! I spaced out when writing that, I updated it to fix the issue

Comment: Which space are you referring to?

Comment: I updated it again. I'm sorry; having spacey morning, shouldn't be answering I guess. it should work fine now. Just copy my updated code and it (should) have no problem. Spacey as in my mindset is out there. Not as in something in the code.

Comment: Now, I have `syntax error, unexpected '$query' (T_VARIABLE)`

Comment: Add a semi-colon to the end of the first query string. I updated my code to show you. Sorry again.

Comment: Thank you it is working now. Are there any other resources to learn about PDO?

Comment: I suggest reading this article, itll give you the run down of PDO, MySQLi, and explains how MySQL is now depreciated: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php-database-access-are-you-doing-it-correctly--net-25338

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape data before you insert it into the database. A stray apostrophe in the description is causing you problems:

```
$descr = mysql_real_escape_string($descr);
```

Please, [stop using `mysql_*` functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation).

- Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).